# How do I submit call handler on radio button selection?

Tags: 7, javascript, hooks, polls

I use the [advanced poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll)s module in Drupal 7. I am trying to alter the behaviour so that the vote is submitted as soon as the radio button is selected (without having to hit *Vote*).

The module is using an ajax callback:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'advpoll_form_submit',
  'wrapper' => 'advpoll-form-' . $values->nid,
  'name' => 'submit1',
),
'#id' => 'edit-submit-advpoll-' . $values->nid,
'#value' => t('Vote'),
```

);

How can I invoke this callback with radio buttons?

I am happy for a quick and dirty javascript/jQuery solution as time is a real factor.

I have tried a jQuery solution:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  $('#advpoll-form-296').trigger('click');
});
```

However this is not invoking the action as expected.

I cannot call submit() as I don't want to cause a page reload.

I have managed to get my original code to fire by adding a click event to the ajax array in the .module file.

advpoll.module:

```
function advpoll_choice_form($form, &$form_state, $values) {

$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'advpoll_form_submit',
  'wrapper' => 'advpoll-form-' . $values->nid,
  'name' => 'submit1',
  'event' => 'click', //Added click event
),
'#id' => 'edit-submit-advpoll-' . $values->nid,
'#value' => t('Vote'),
```

);

I am aware I should not override code within the module. How would I go about getting this into a theme hook?

Comment: have you tried using the jquery submit() function? https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Quick and dirty: `$('#advpoll-form-296').submit();`. The Drupal way is more complicated

Comment: Cannot use submit() without reloading. Edited question to include more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```

You might want to qualify the selector for `$('input[type="radio"]')` to the scope of the form you're working with, else if you include this in a JavaScript file that's accessed on many different pages, you'll definitely run into problems!

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/8448bjiywnVtbT3CV6s6?p=info

Comment: can't use submit() without causing a reload. Good suggestion on selector. Updated question with more detail. I just need to work out how to add the click event as a theme hook.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this was posted but I hope this answer can help anyway

The simple way I found to do it (I'm using the advpoll module as well) is to add the same AJAX handler to the options dropdown using `hook_form_alter`

So, in my custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // The submit form has ID advpoll_choice_form
  if ($form_id == 'advpoll_choice_form') {
    foreach ($form as $key => &$value) {
      // It seems that the radio buttons are under an array labelled 'choice_X' 
      // where X is the number of options you have, so this just checks
      // it's doing it to the correct one
      if (substr($key, 0, 7) == 'choice_') {
        // Apply the same AJAX handler the submit button has to the radio buttons
        $value['#ajax'] = $form['submit']['#ajax'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future